# How to bind Map<String,Object> to @ConfigurationProperties at top level?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Example YAML

```yaml
apps:
  google:
    name: Google
    type: Search Engine
  bing:
    name: Bing
    type: Search Engine
```

Example Spring bean

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("apps")
public class Apps extends HashMap<String, AppConfig> {

  @Getter
  @Setter
  static class AppConfig {
    private String name;
    private String type;
  }
}
```

That doesn't seem to work. Any way to bind map from YAML at top level?

The following will work but this requires an extra property at lower level in YAML file.

```yaml
apps:
  config:
    google:
      name: Google
      type: Search Engine
    bing:
      name: Bing
      type: Search Engine
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("apps")
public class Apps {

  private Map<String, AppConfig> config;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  static class AppConfig {
    private String name;
    private String type;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be enough for you

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties  // <--------
public class Apps {

  private Map<String, AppConfig> apps;  // <-------

  @Getter
  @Setter
  static class AppConfig {
    private String name;
    private String type;
  }
}
```

to map the example yaml of

```
apps:
  google:
    name: Google
    type: Search Engine
  bing:
    name: Bing
    type: Search Engine
```

By modyfying `@ConfigurationProperties("apps")` into `@ConfigurationProperties` you instruct that you want the parsing to start from top level of yaml which is `apps`. Your version with `@ConfigurationProperties("apps")` asks spring to start the mapping from first level children element after `apps`.

By naming the java class field to `apps` on the line `private Map<String, AppConfig> apps;` you instruct spring that it expects to find a yaml element named `apps` from where it starts reading, which according to the previous explanation will be the root of the yaml.

Comment: It works but IntelliJ IDEA complains that "Prefix must be specified" when @ConfigurationProperties has no arguments and that makes me wonder if it will work in the future.

Comment: @Politechniczny https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20885#issuecomment-611059344 it seems that this message could be a bit better since `must` is not correct. `should be specified` message is more appropriate since this would be better practice but no necessity according to spring boot team.

Comment: `makes me wonder if it will work in the future` if you keep your yaml consistent in the form of `google:
    name: Google
    type: Search Engine` it would not have any problem in the future even if you add even more such configurations. But if you add some other top level configurations of different form then it might stop working. This is why it would be best to move those configurations one level lower than top level form yaml, like `config: apps: google: ....` and then use the `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="config")`

Comment: @Politechniczny doing the above will be considered best practice since that way you will be able to modify the top level of your `yaml` without affecting the level that interests you here of `config: apps: google...`